# A question about eigenvectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $T\in L(V,V)$, and let $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ be a basis of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T$, belonging to eigenvalues $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ respectively. Then $Tv_i=a_iv_i$. Prove that $f(T)=0$ where $$f(x)=(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)\dots(x-a_n)$$

By what I have understood, $f(T)=0$ only when $f(T)$ maps every vector in $V$ to $0$.

Take the special case $n=2$.

Say we have $f(T)=(T-a_1)(T-a_2)$. If $f(T)=0$, we have $[(T-a_1)(T-a_2)](v_1+v_2)=0$, as $v_1+v_2\in V$. Now $[(T-a_1)(T-a_2)](v_1+v_2)=(T-a_1)(v_1+v_2)\times (T-a_2)(v_1+v_2)=$ $$[0+(T-a_1)v_2]\times [(T-a_2)v_1+0]=(T-a_1)v_2\times (T-a_2)v_1$$ How do we show this maps to $0$??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the easy case of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem).

Comment: The proposed arithmetic rule $AB(v+w)=(A(v+w))\times (B(v+w))$ is obviously wrong. Since here $A$ and $B$ commute, the correct application of the distributional law is $AB(v+w)=ABv+ABw=B(Av)+A(Bw)$.

Answer (score 1):

To show a map is the zero map, show that it takes an entire basis to zero.  Then it must take every vector, a linear combination of basis vectors, to zero by linearity.

To show that your expression takes a basis to zero, compute: $$f(T)=(T-a_1)(T-a_2)(T-a_3)\dots(T-a_n)$$
which is some operator and let it act on the only basis you've got:  $$f(T)(v_1)=(T-a_1)(T-a_2)(T-a_3)\dots(T-a_n)(v_1)$$ $$ = (T-a_2)(T-a_3)\dots(T-a_n)(Tv_1-a_1v_1) $$
and note that the $T-a_1$ term annihilates $v_1$ via the eigenvalue-eigenvector equation you quote.  Similarly, the $T-a_i$ term annihilates $v_i$ for each of the basis vectors.  Therefore $f(T)$ annihilates an entire basis so is the zero map.

Answer (score 0):

We think of $f(T)$ as a map from $V$ to $V$ given by $f(T)(v)=(T-a_1I)(T-a_2I)\dots(T-a_nI)(v)$. It is not hard to see that $f(T)$ is a linear transformation. A nice fact about linear transformations is that their image is completely determined by where they send the vectors in a given basis. So, what is $f(T)(v_i)$ for any $i = 1,2,\dots,n$?

Comment: Yeah I got that. I know that $f(T)(v_i)=0$ for all $i=1,2,3,\dots$. I'm worried about linear combinations of $v_i$ though. Like $v_1+v_2$, as given in the example above.

Comment: Well, suppose $v = c_1v_1+\dots+c_nv_n$. Then $f(T)(v)=c_1f(T)(v_1)+\dots+c_nf(T)(v_n)$ since $f(T)$ is a linear transformation...

Comment: Yeah. Totally should have seen that. "$f(T)$ is a linear operator too". Thanks loads! Can't upvote this due to my non-member status, but thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Just apply $f(T)$ to a generic linear combination $v=\sum \lambda^i v_i$. The last factor
$$
(T-a_nI)\left(\sum \lambda^i v_i\right)=\sum \lambda^i (Tv_i - a_nv_i)=\sum \lambda^i (Tv_i - a_nv_i)=\sum \lambda^i (a_iv_i-a_nv_i)=\sum \lambda^i (a_i-a_n) v_i
$$
so now you have only $n-1$ coefficients left...